# how do I give permission to bash to run to multiple gcloud commands from local jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am practicing model deployment to GCP cloud ML Engine. However, I receive errors stated below when I execute the following code section in my local jupyter notebook. Please note I do have bash installed in my local PC and environment variables are properly set.

%%bash

gcloud config set project $PROJECT

gcloud config set compute/region $REGION

Error messages:

-bash: line 1: /mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: Permission denied
-bash: line 2: /mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: Permission denied

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'gcloud config set project $PROJECT\ngcloud config set compute/region $REGION\n\n'' returned non-zero exit status 126.

Comment: "Permission denied" means exactly what it sounds like. You lack execute or perhaps read permission to the file you are trying to run as a command. Perhaps it is stored on a partition which does not support setting the executable bit at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you installed Google Cloud SDK with root?

try

`sudo gcloud config set project $PROJECT`

and

`sudo gcloud config set compute/region $REGION`

Comment: It works with !gcloud config set project $PROJECT. Neither works with sudo nor %%bash. Any reason why?